# Automorphisms of partitions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, partitions, automorphism-groups

I would like to know whether the notion of automorphism of the set of partitions of a positive integer $n$ has been considered so far or not. To make things clearer, I say that a partition of $n$ in $k$ summands $s_1,s_2,...s_k$ sorted in decreasing order has signature $(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)$ if and only if $\forall i\in\{1,\cdots,m\},\ \ a_{i}>0$ and $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i}=k}$ and each $a_i$ is the multiplicity of a summand: $a_1$ is the number of times the largest summand appears, $a_2$ the number of times the second largest summand appears, and so on.

I thus call "automorphism of the set of partitions of $n$" any bijective map sending any partition of $n$ in $k$ summands of signature $(a_1,a_2,...a_m)$ to a partition of $n$ in $k$ summands of signature $(a_1, a_2,...,a_m)$.
For example, one can consider a map sending the partition $(6,5,1)$ of $12$ to the partition $(6,4,2)$.

If I'm not mistaken, the group of automorphisms of the set of partitions of $n$ is a subgroup $Aut_{Part}(n)$ of $S_{p(n)}$, where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$. What can be said about this group? Is it necessarily abelian? Solvable? Any interesting reference available on-line freely about related subjects?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition of the signature of a partition does not mention the partition except for the number of parts $k$. Something is wrong.

Comment: don't you mean that your group is a subgroup of $S_{p(n)}$, where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$?

Comment: Hmm, I can't see where the problem is. In $12=6+6$, $k=2$ and the signature is $(1,1)$. In $12=4+4+3+1$, $k=4$ and the signature is $(2,1,1)$. One should consider the terms appearing in the signature as "multiplicities" of summands. Is it clearer that way?

Comment: Good point, marcel (un compatriote ? :-)). I'm gonna edit.

Comment: I still don't know what the signature is of a partition. How do you get $(1,1)$ from the partition $6+6$ of $12$?

Comment: Please clarify: "any bijective map": a map between which set and which set? A bijection from a set to itself is called a *permutation* of the set, and you should specify the set.

Comment: @Douglas Zare: yes indeed, it is $(2)$ and not $(1,1)$.

Comment: Or are you saying that there are many different $m$-tuples that are all the signatures of a partition?

Comment: Please actually define what you mean.

Comment: If you reask  a similar question on MathSE, use more appropriate tags. This is not number theory. You can use finite groups, group theory, possibly symmetric group or anything related to partitions.

Comment: To me group theory is part of algebra, which can be used as a tool in many different areas such as, among others, number theory. As I deal with partitions of a positive integer, the number-theory tag definitely doesn't come out of the blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(n,\alpha)$ be the set of partitions of $n$ with signature $\alpha$. Such a set is invariant under your group, and any permutation of its elements is an automorphism. Your group is just $$G=\Pi_\alpha S_{|P(n,\alpha)|}.$$

Comment: You probably mean $\prod_\alpha$? Or I ignore some use of the $\otimes$ sign. Anyway I have the same understanding of the question (which makes it trivial)

Comment: Thank you Marcel for both understanding and clarifying what I meant. But I must admit I'm in the same situation as YCor.

Comment: I mean direct product of groups. How do you denote this?

Comment: $\Pi_\alpha$. I agree with this answer even though I don't know what type of object $\alpha$ is, a composition or a partition.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN this kind of question is more appropriate at math StackExchange. (btw I am not french, but brazilian)

Comment: @DouglasZare $\alpha$ is neither a partition nor a composition of $n$, it is just a multiset containing the multiplicities of the parts of a partition.

Comment: The last edit made it a composition of $k$, not a multiset. The order matters now.

Comment: Besides being what I said, it is a *partition* of $k$. So $(3,2,2)$ and $(5,1,1)$ are partitions of $7$, both with signature $(2,1)$.

Comment: Obrigado Marcel. More exactly, the partitions you consider have signature $(1,2)$, not $(2,1)$. But otherwise, I'm ok to see my question migrated to Math.SE.

Comment: @Marcel: A partition of $k$ would be unordered. A composition is an ordered sum. Anyway, there is nothing deep here.

Comment: @DouglasZare I agree with everything you said, and it does'n contradict anything I said :)

Comment: What I said was meant to contradict where you said, "it is just a multiset" in the comment at 18:52 and then where you kept emphasizing that it is a multiset/partition at 18:58. It's not just a multiset, the order matters, according to Sylvain Julien. The partitions $3+3+1$ and $5+1+1$ produce the signatures $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$, which are considered different compositions of $3$ and different signatures, whereas if they were just multisets or partitions as you said, they would be the same. If that's clear, then I'm done.

Comment: No, it is a multiset and a partition. Julien just chooses to write the elements in increasing order instead of decreasing. At least that is what I understood.

Comment: Then our understandings contradict each other. Mine is based on things like where the question defines $a_1$ now. That is why I asked for a clarification on the definition of the signature. It would have been reasonable to have multiple interpretations initially.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, because Julien is using a non-standard definition of signature.. The *standard* definition is as the multiset of multiplicities. Sorry. Anyway, hardly matters.